# Output precision is reduced to the precision of the operands

Tags: .net, math, expression, precision, delphi-prism

I am getting warning message on the following expression.

```
(400*ev.PageBounds.Width)/2400
```

Warning message is **Output precision is reduced to the precision of the operands**.

Why? Can I just ignore it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use operands of wider precision:

```
(400.0*ev.PageBounds.Width)/2400.0
```

or cast them:

```
(((double)400)*v.PageBounds.Width)/(double)2400
```

etc. Note that it is the `400` what dictates the type of the result, you may skip casting the `2400`

Edit: no, in general you should not ignore it. The message warns you that dividing BLAH by 2400 may result in fractions that would be truncated. Ie. 3500 / 2400 = 1. It would be done in such way, when all of your operands are integral, for example:

```
2 * 4 / 10 * 10 ==== 0
```

while

```
2 * 4.0 / 10 * 10 ==== 8
```